# Angular5 - use key/value pair for select option

Tags: angular5, key-value, ngfor

I've started working with angular5 and I'm trying to get the value of a select option and it's assigned ID onChange.

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
// Services
import { LookupDataService } from '../../../service/lookup-data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'diversity-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './diversity-dropdown.component.html',
  providers: [LookupDataService]
})
export class DiversityDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  diversityForm: IDiversityForm[];
  title = 'Lookup data';
  selectedDiversity = '';

  constructor(private readonly lookupDataService: LookupDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lookupDataService.getDiversityForm().subscribe((diversityForm: IDiversityForm[]) => {
      this.diversityForm = diversityForm;
      console.log(diversityForm);

      }
    );
  }

  onChange($event) {
    console.log($event);
  }

}
```

**View**

```
<div *ngFor='let section of diversityForm'>
  <span class="label label-default">{{section.labelText}}</span>

<select (change)="onChange($event)" ng-model="">
<<option *ngFor='let dropdown of section.lookupDropdowns' id="{{dropdown.labelText}}" value="{{dropdown.value}} {{dropdown.labelText}}">{{dropdown.value}}</option>
</select>

  <br />
</div>
```

**Data**

[image]

I've tried $event.target.id but in the console it's an empty string. $event.target.value works however.

Is there an easy way of doing what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

**[Stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-select)**

You should use select in this way:

HTML:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="newGovId.first_id_type" (change)="function($event)">
      <option [ngValue]="null">Select something</option>
      <option *ngFor="let option of options"
              [ngValue]="option.value" [innerHtml]="option.text"></option>
</select>
```

The context of each option should be in the variable you're looping.